# Per row, which columns are NA

Tags: r

Per row in data frame 'd' I want to know which columns doesnt contain NA. The output I want is which columns. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
a <- c(1,3,4,5,NA)
b <- c(1,NA,NA,5,9)
c <- c(NA,3,4,5,3)

d <- data.frame(a,b,c)
d
  a  b  c
  1  1 NA
  3 NA  3
  4 NA  4
  5  5  5
 NA  9  3
```

Wanted output:

```
row1= column a,b
row2 = column a,c
row3 = column b,c
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `apply` rowwise :

```
cols <- names(d)
apply(!is.na(d), 1, function(x) toString(cols[x]))
#[1] "a, b"    "a, c"    "a, c"    "a, b, c" "b, c"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a <- c(1,3,4,5,NA)
b <- c(1,NA,NA,5,9)
c <- c(NA,3,4,5,3)

d <- data.frame(a,b,c)

d1 <- d %>% 
  mutate(isNA = rowSums(is.na(d)))

# Output:
   a  b  c isNA
1  1  1 NA    1
2  3 NA  3    1
3  4 NA  4    1
4  5  5  5    0
5 NA  9  3    1
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be:

```
which(!sapply(d, is.na), arr.ind = TRUE)

      row col
 [1,]   1   1
 [2,]   2   1
 [3,]   3   1
 [4,]   4   1
 [5,]   1   2
 [6,]   4   2
 [7,]   5   2
 [8,]   2   3
 [9,]   3   3
[10,]   4   3
[11,]   5   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dapply` from `collapse` which would be more efficient in rowwise computation

```
library(collapse)
nm1 <- names(d)
dapply(d, FUN = function(x) toString(nm1[!is.na(x)]), MARGIN = 1)
#[1] "a, b"    "a, c"    "a, c"    "a, b, c" "b, c"
```